# Objects don't follow the particles system/vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups

I'm totally new to blender and I'm trying to learn it for scientific pourposes; in particular for creating crystal lattices. In order to do that, I found an addon called Bravais Lattice Creator (BLC), which, sadly, works only on blender 2.79. However the view of the latest version, 2.91, is much better than the one of 2.79, allowing me a better stacking of the diferent crystal layers.
However when I open a file made with Blender 2.79 in Blender 2.91, what happens is that if I try to just move a crystal lattice (vertex groups with a sphere for each vertex), blender moves only the vertex group, while the spheres are totally impossible to be moved.[image: Before moving] Moreover it see the two system as one; infact if I change, for example, the spheres with cubes, it changes correctly, but still impossibile to move.
[image: After moving]
In the version 2.79 this problem is not present.
(Moreover Blender 2.91 can exploits the graphic card of my notebook, a nvidia 1650 ti)

Does anyone has some suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: One thing to try is if you *open* the file from 2.7- versions with 2.8+, uncheck Load UI in the Open File dialog options. That way settings from old UI won't be intended to be used. In this particular case, you could skip that and only append objects from the 2.7 file

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of a thing where in blender 2.80 and up, auto cache refreshing got scrambled. First it refreshed when it shouldn't've, now it has sometimes not been refreshing when it should've: You probably need to refresh the particle cache manually.

One way that seems fairly solid is change some fundamental setting to the particles/simulation, then immediately change it back. Number of particles is one, particle size is not.

This is just a guess, I hope it helps.